# Two conditions get evaluated correctly but wrong block is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

`data` contains more or less this piece:

```
[
    {"code": "F1", "description": "Item 1", "quantity": 2, "group": "G1"},
    {"code": "C4", "description": "Item 4", "quantity": 6, "group": "GS"},
    {"code": "D2", "description": "Item 2", "quantity": 6, "group": "G1"}
]
```

Also, there are keys I'd like to be present inside the JSON above:

```py
keys = ['code', 'description', 'quantity', 'group_code', 'group_name']
```

So, the `data` gets loaded and operations begin. This loop is executed:

```py
for d in data:
    for i in d:
        print('looped data:', d, ', key:', i)
        print('str(i) in keys:', str(i) in keys)
        if isinstance(d[i], int):
            print('int detected ' * 3)
            try:
                if d[i] and str(i) in keys:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                                       + "\" isn\'t correct in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
        else:
            print('not int detected')
            try:
                if len(d[i]) > 0 and str(i) in keys:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                                       + "\" doesn\'t exist in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
```

After the run I'd expect an error to encounter, because `group` key is not in `keys` array and condition `str(i) in keys` should evaluate to not passed because it's `False`, but there are no exceptions raised:

```
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False ########### <-- no exception!
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False ########### <-- no exception!
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False ########### <-- no exception!
not int detected
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `if len(d[i]) > 0 and str(i) in keys:` is not throwing any exception because `d[i]` is valid.  Thus,  you are not seeing an exception.  Did you mean to do `if len(d[i]) > 0 and str(i) in keys: ... else: raise ValidationError`?

Comment: An `if` statement won't raise an exception just because the condition is falsey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you meant to do:

```
for d in data:
    for i in d:
        print('looped data:', d, ', key:', i)
        print('str(i) in keys:', str(i) in keys)
        if isinstance(d[i], int):
            print('int detected ' * 3)
            if d[i] and str(i) in keys:
                pass
            else: 
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                    + "\" isn\'t correct in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
        else:
            print('not int detected')
            if len(d[i]) > 0 and str(i) in keys:
                pass
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                    + "\" doesn\'t exist in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
```

The problem with your original code is you expect `d[i]` to throw a `KeyError`, but in fact `d[i]` will *always be valid* as you are looping directly within `for i in d:`.  Also if anything, you should be catching the `try: ... except KeyError:` before the point of `if isinstance(d[i], int):` (not that it applies in this case).

For your reference, you might also consider doing this instead:

```
for d in data:
    for i, item in d.items():
        # instead of d[i], just use item directly
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you better understand the issue I printed both `d[i]` and `[i]`.
Input:

```
data = [{"code": "F1", "description": "Item 1", "quantity": 2, "group": "G1"},
    {"code": "C4", "description": "Item 4", "quantity": 6, "group": "GS"},
    {"code": "D2", "description": "Item 2", "quantity": 6, "group": "G1"}
]
keys = ['code', 'description', 'quantity', 'group_code', 'group_name']
for d in data:
    for i in d:
        print('looped data:', d, ', key:', i)
        print('str(i) in keys:', str(i) in keys)
        if isinstance(d[i], int):
            print('int detected ' * 3)
            try:
                if d[i] and str(i) in keys:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                                       + "\" isn\'t correct in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
        else:
            print('not int detected')
            print(d[i])
            print(i)
            try:
                if len(d[i]) > 0 and str(i) in keys:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Error! Parameter \"" + str(i)
                                       + "\" doesn\'t exist in <<" + str(d) + ">>!")
```

Output:

```
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
F1
code
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
Item 1
description
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'F1', 'description': 'Item 1', 'quantity': 2, 'group': 'G1'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False
not int detected
G1
group
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
C4
code
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
Item 4
description
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'C4', 'description': 'Item 4', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'GS'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False
not int detected
GS
group
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: code
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
D2
code
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: description
str(i) in keys: True
not int detected
Item 2
description
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: quantity
str(i) in keys: True
int detected int detected int detected
looped data: {'code': 'D2', 'description': 'Item 2', 'quantity': 6, 'group': 'G1'} , key: group
str(i) in keys: False
not int detected
G1
group
```

In the cases you describe as `errors` the condition for the if is met and it just follows the `True` value for the condition and `pass`.